# How can I run two processes for different listview values in the same listview box?

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing

I'm working on a bigger program, but the operation it does for each value in a listbox takes a long time. I want to speed this up by performing the same process for multiple values in the same listviewbox, basically trying to add some type of Parallel operation logic to get the job done.

I created a quick program that is a very very simple version of the bigger program I'm working in, I'm hoping someone can constructively point me in the right direction.

Is there a way with a listviewbox that I can start at the top and the bottom of a list simultaneously and have each one work their way until they meet in the middle? I can't wrap my head around another way to do this.

Here's example 'code' of what I'm doing now with a background worker, nothing fancy (again, this is a mocked up program because of the "complexity" of the actual program I'm working on.)

```
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        ListViewItem lst = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

        foreach (ListViewItem user in listView1.Items)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(user.SubItems[0].Text);
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; // I know, but this is an example program, so I'm using this for ny own sanity sake right now.
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Here's the GUI part of the program

[image]

I hope this makes sense. If not, I can elaborate further, but this is the gist of what I'm trying to do.

(I have tried looking on stack overflow for similar questions, but I haven't found that helps me because they're either in different languages Or they go on a tangent that I can't follow because it's beyond the scope of my program and I don't understand how to adapt their answers to my program.)

**UPDATE W/ ANSWER**

In the event this helps anyway in the future, I took the advice in the comments and implemented `Parallel.ForEach` in my code. Because it's a listview, I had to be a little more creative with my approach.

My ForEach statement looks like this now:

```
var opts = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.50) * 1.0)) };

Parallel.ForEach<ListViewItem>(lstBackupUsers.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>(),opts, name => { // Long stuff to do here });
```

Basically, I removed the regular "foreach" command in my backgroundworker task and replaced it with the Parallel.ForEach above. For reference, I had to use the ParallelOptions to limit the amount of resources (in this case, 50% of my resources.)

**Update 2 (with odd problem)**

So the statement above works as expected and it works well, Except the Parallel.ForEach(...) statement doesn't reiterate through my whole listbox **when using** the MaxDegreeOfParallelism argument. If I don't use that in the ForEach statement, then I receive "Out of memory" exceptions, but if I do use it, then my ForEach runs for a few rows then it stops.

It's like this (to me):

If I set MaxDegreeOfParallelism, it only reiterates through the number of cores I have in my machine against the listview box (no matter what value I tell MaxDegreeOfParallelism to use.) So example:

I have a listview box with 20 rows, my computer only reiterates through 8 of them then the ForEach stops (my machine has 8 cores right now.)

Any idea on what else I can do?

Thank you!

**Update 3**

I now have `var result = Parallel.ForEach` and I'm checking for `result.IsCompleted`, which helped point me in the right direction to address the loop.

Comment: have you tried using `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: Thanks gilmishal, I have not looked at that. oops.. hit return a little too quick. so I'd do something like `ListViewItem user` `List<ListViewItem> username = new List<ListViewItem>(user)` then `Parallel.ForEach(username, row => { // background_dowork stuff here? });`

Comment: If you going to all these tasks at the same time then *"can i start at both the top and very bottom ..."*  will not add anything to the solution.

Comment: I was hoping it would have sped up the program by doing 2 users at once instead of one a time.. Is that logic not correct if the program started at the top of the listbox and the bottom (going upwards) at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need the Background-Worker for this task. As gilmishal mentioned in comment you can use a Parallel.Foreach. This Class is inside the Task Namespace which holds the new async TAP Pattern from Microsoft. If you use Multithreading you should take a look at this namespace. The Parallel.Foreach starts you action within the method body in a new Thread (if this is sensefull). So you don't need to start at top and bottom. The loop starts for every element of your list at nearly the same time (parallel).

```
Parallel.ForEach(username, row => { // do your long running stuff });
```

**UDPATE:**

Parallel.ForEach is not executed in extra Thread by default. So the UI can freeze. For avoiding this behaviour you should run the Parallel.ForEach in an extra Task. This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392.aspx) points out why you shouldn't run a Parallel.ForEeach in a UI Thread. So for stop freezing UI do following:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        Parallel.ForEach(username, row => { // background_dowork stuff here? });    
    });
 }
```

Make sure you don't access any UI Components in the separated thread.

Comment: Thanks Sebi for taking your time to answer this. I have a follow up question to this (and probably a couple more): I'd still want to use a background worker, right? otherwise the way my program works now would be "frozen" while performing the tasks... Unless the `Parralel.ForEach` class is the "new" background worker? (Sorry, I've never heard of/used a Parallel class at this point)

Comment: @MichaelTucker Hi the Parallel.Foreach is not the new BackgroundWorker. It's just one possibility from the new TAP-Pattern which is included in the System.Task namespace. System.Task is the new BackgroundWorker if you want so. I will update my answer, so that your form won't freeze.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I'd give you two thumbs up if I could. I'm going to add an extra comment here shortly about what mine looks like, but I will be marking yours as the answer. Thanks again

Comment: @MichaelTucker your welcome. If you have any further questions...ask ;)

Comment: Thanks Sebi, I do appreciate your help. I updated my post with another problem I've ran across. Would you happen to have any ideas I can try? Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelTucker Hi are you sure your Parallel.Foreach is completly done? I could be that the Parallel.Foreach still runs after your few iterations. Parallel.Foreach returns before it's completed in many cases. To check this use var result = Parallel.Foreach(//your stuff); result.IsCompleted; Please check this.

Comment: Good grief. Thanks for that, that pointed me in the right direction. I have to figure out why I'm going back to a System out of memory exception. Task Manager barely acknowledges any memory being consumed when this program is running, but that may be a different problem than the original scope of this question.

Comment: @MichaelTucker Yes please create a new question for this.